# Removing an Event Listener from an iFrame's Parent Window

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have this code...

```
var t = "onorientationchange" in window, o = t ? "orientationchange" : "resize";
window.addEventListener && window.addEventListener(o, function () {
    location.reload()
}, !1)
```

I would like to remove the event listener for "resize".  I do not have direct access to the code but I am loading up other code via an iframe on the same domain.  Currently I'm resizing the iframe dynamically based on it's content with no issue.  My question is, can I remove the resize listener from the parent window via code loaded in the iframe?  If so, what would that code look like?

The biggest issue is that I have a form in the iframe and whenever the page is resized it's reloading the whole page and any data that was in the form gets erased.  Not ideal and no way for me to directly fix it.  I'd hate for users to lose who knows how much just because they decided to maximize the screen.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you think it's possible?

Comment: With an iFrame, the parent will ALWAYS take precedence over the iFrame itself ...  Unless you have direct access to the parent's code, this is not only impossible, it's dangerous (which is WHY it's impossible).

Comment: you need a ref to the handler function, which is impossible as coded because it's anon. you can put a flag in the handler, or make the handler reachable from the global scope so that you can pass it to removeEventListener(). if you can't mod the parent, you have to detect if your're in a frame, and abort early.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I wanted to check and make sure I was correct...hoping I was wrong though.  Thanks!